# How could I read multidimensional arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, ajax, multidimensional-array, nested

I post a javascript array of arrays to C# server as follows:

```
    var myArr= [
        [15,0,1,2],
        [16,3,4,5]
    ];
    alert("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(myArr));
     var postdata = JSON.stringify(myArr);
         try {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "SaveSendPdfHandler.aspx",
                 cache: false,
                 data: postdata,
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: getSuccess,
                 error: getFail
             });
         } catch (e) {
             alert("Ex: " + e);
         }
         function getSuccess(result) {
             alert("Success Data : " + result);
     };
         function getFail(result) {
             alert("Error Data: " + result);
     };
```

How could I read the data in C# so that I could get each value in each of the arrays?

Comment: I believe [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is the canonical library used to parse JSON in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you should just be able to do:

```
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<int>>>(json);
```

People tend to use `List<T>` for ease of use but you could conceivably use a standard array in which case you could replace out `List<List<int>>` with `int[][]` depending on your use case.

This assumes the JSON output is:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the type of the object receiving this request (assuming all integers) is `List<List<int>>`